# Continuous Integration of Scala projects and arbitrary statistics over time

Tags: scala, graph, statistics, continuous-integration, sbt

I am looking for a [**Continuous Integration**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) tool for various [**Scala**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_%28programming_language%29) projects. So far I found [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/), which apparently supports Scala project via a plugin for [Sbt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Build_Tool), and [Pulse](http://zutubi.com/products/pulse/), which does not directly support Scala projects but claims that it makes it easy to integrate any command line build tool, which matches Sbt. I don't have any practical experience with CI, but read a couple of articles about it, usually related to Java.

Besides the usual features, e.g. support for various **code versioning systems** and **publishing nightly builds** I'd like to be able to **record a bunch of statistics, plot them over time and trigger notifications** if certain numbers change unexpectedly, i.e., by more than a defined factor. In essence, each test from a test suite prints a number of statistics at the end, which could be extracted by a regular expression and then persisted (associated with the test case they came from).

Ideally, there also is an easy way to create queries over the recorded statistics, e.g., to compare the last run of the test suite with an earlier one. However, this is probably not something that can be done directly in a CI tool, but it should at least be possible to export the recorded data in a queryable format, e.g., XML or JSON.

Any hints, links or experience reports are welcome!

**EDIT 1:**

The statistics are not JVM-statistics in some sense, e.g., code coverage or memory consumption. They are related to the actual work performed by the projects, e.g., the number of comparisons performed by a sorting algorithm, or the number of conflicting assignments in a SAT solver. The numbers are printed to stdio at the end of each run, or written to a file. The CI tool should "only" allow me to render them as graphs over time, or to perform simple analyses (sum, meridian), or to send a mail when a number diverts from the average.

Comment: Note that Jenkins also supports Scala on Maven, Ant or pretty much any JVM builder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write a Jenkins plugin to gather this stdout and do all you are asking for. As an alternative to grabbing standard out, redirect that output to a file, and have the plugin read the file.

At any rate, there are many plugins doing that sort of thing. Just look up Jenkins tutorials, and maybe grab a plugin that does something similar as an example.

As a final note, I know that [Travis CI](http://travis-ci.org/) also supports Scala, though I have no experience with it, so I have no clue if they support your requirements or not.

Comment: Do you happen to know any of these many plugins in particular?

Comment: @mhs As in how they are written, or using them? I use some of them, such as the [Warnings Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Warnings+Plugin) which can scan console output and files, and accepts user-defined parsers for warning messages. That should cover most things you may want, though at 50k lines it might be a bit daunting to examine. Plenty of parsers and tests, though, so maybe not.

Answer (score 4):

We (Atlassian – the company I work for) sell [Bamboo](http://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo/overview) and it does have some support for SBT as well as Maven builds (with the maven-scala plugin). We do use these internally for our Scala projects and it wasn't that hard to set up. It has most of the historical features you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For Scala support in CI systems it is more relevant to check the support of the build tool.

Among others maven, gradle, ant and sbt can handle Scala and I would expect every CI system to support at least the first 3. Jenkins certainly does.

For gathering statistics, look for tools that work on java byte code they should be able to handle byte code generated by the Scala Compiler as well.

[Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/) gathers lots of statistics and makes them available via a website. It would be worth an experiment to see which statistics are meaningful for java.

For triggering events on sudden changes you could query the database of Sonar.

Update regarding the updated question:

Teamcity supports rendering of custom charts:

http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Custom+Chart

http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-ReportingBuildStatistics

http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-provideStatsUsingFile

Used that successful a couple of years back.

Jenkins has a plugin for this, but I personally didn't get it to work, when I tried for a short time.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Measurement+Plots+Plugin

Comment: I already stated in the question that Jenkins supports Sbt.
Please see EDIT 1, I don't think that Java byte code tools are helpful here.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer and providing the links!